# Swift: Update/replace an object in array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am stuck with a problem that actually seems simpler.

1. I have an array `preferenceSet` of type `Preference` using which I am populating my rows of `tableView` section. (i.e. in my tableView, each section has a set of Preferences).
2. The tableView has sections that can be **collapsed/expanded**. (the toggle happens when user taps on section header)

Now, for a preference, when there is a change of value (`true` to `false` or `false` to `true`), I make an API call and when it is `success`, I update back my `preferenceSet` with the new `updatedPrefSet`. This works very well in case of one **expanded** section. Now the problem is when there are multiple **expanded** sections.

I am doing below to filter out what preferences should be updated based on `updatedPrefSet`.
**Code:**

```
func expandOrCollapseCategory(sender: CategoryGestureRecoginzer, preferenceSet: [CustomerPreference]) {
    let updatedPrefSet = preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})                      
                
    for i in 0..<self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode}).count {
                    if self.preferenceSet[i].categoryCode == sender.categoryCode {
                        self.preferenceSet[i].code = updatedPrefSet[i].code
                        self.preferenceSet[i].dataType = updatedPrefSet[i].dataType
                        self.preferenceSet[i].description = updatedPrefSet[i].description
                        self.preferenceSet[i].name = updatedPrefSet[i].name
                        self.preferenceSet[i].preferenceValues = updatedPrefSet[i].preferenceValues
                        self.preferenceSet[i].value = updatedPrefSet[i].value
                    }
                }
                
                let sectionNumber = self.preferenceCategories?.firstIndex(where: {$0.code == sender.categoryCode})
                
                self.preferencesTableView.reloadSections([sectionNumber!], with: .fade)

}
```

Here, `categoryCode` is the property that I depend on to filter the objects. I compare the received `updatedPrefSet` `categoryCode` (with the help of `sender`) with `self.preferenceSet` `categoryCode` and trying to replace only that set of objects in my `self.preferenceSet`.

Also, this is the same method am using also to **expand/collapse** the sections where there are no conflicts between the two.

I verified my `updatedPrefSet` that comes back from service call, and it is always correct! (verified from Postman). The problem lies only with updating my `self.preferenceSet`. I am not sure where I am going wrong in looping or updating the objects.

In the [video link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OE3XlyRBIxo&feature=youtu.be), value changes in the first section work well and as expected. Second section doesn't update intended value and the third section doesn't update anything at all. Even though I get a successful updated object response (`updatedPrefSet`) every time.

**UPDATE 1**:
I updated my code as below (thanks @Robert, for confirming same with your comment). But the behavior still the same. Value changes of section that is expanded first works well. For any other section changes, the updated value doesn't reflect. :|

```
for i in 0..<self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode}).count {
                
                if self.preferenceSet[i].categoryCode == sender.categoryCode {
                    self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})[i].code = updatedPrefSet[i].code
                    self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})[i].dataType = updatedPrefSet[i].dataType
                    self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})[i].description = updatedPrefSet[i].description
                    self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})[i].name = updatedPrefSet[i].name
                    self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})[i].preferenceValues = updatedPrefSet[i].preferenceValues
                    self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})[i].value = updatedPrefSet[i].value
                }
            }
```

Here is my `**numberOfRows**` and `**cellForRowAt**`

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let preferenceCategories = self.preferenceCategories else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            
            let categoryCode = preferenceCategories[indexPath.section].code
            
            let filteredPreferenceSet = self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == categoryCode})
            
            if let preferenceDataType = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].dataType {
                
                switch preferenceDataType {
                case "BOOLEAN":
                    let cell = self.preferencesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustPrefSetCell", for: indexPath) as! CustPrefSetCell
                    
                    cell.categoryCode = categoryCode!
                    cell.preferenceName.text = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].name
                    cell.preferenceDescription.text = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].description
                    
                    cell.switchDelegate = self
                    
                    let propertyValue = ((filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].value ?? "false") as NSString).boolValue
                    
                    propertyValue ? cell.preferenceSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true) : cell.preferenceSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
                    
                    cell.preferenceCode = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].code
                    
                    if indexPath.row == filteredPreferenceSet.count - 1 {
                        cell.customSeparator.isHidden = true
                    }
                    else {
                        cell.customSeparator.isHidden = false
                    }
                    
                    return cell
                    
                    
                case "MULTISELECT":
                    let multiSelectCell = self.preferencesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustPrefMultiSelectTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustPrefMultiSelectTableViewCell
                    
                    multiSelectCell.configureCell(of: categoryCode!, with: filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].preferenceValues!)
                    
                    multiSelectCell.preferenceTitle.text = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].name
                    
                    if filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].description != nil {
                        multiSelectCell.preferenceDescription.text = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].description
                    }
                    else {
                        multiSelectCell.preferenceDescription.text = ""
                        multiSelectCell.titleBottomConstraint.constant = 0
                        multiSelectCell.descriptionBottomConstraint.constant = 0
                    }
                    
                    multiSelectCell.multiSelectSwitchDelegate = self
                    
                    multiSelectCell.setNeedsLayout()
                    multiSelectCell.layoutIfNeeded()

                    return multiSelectCell
                    
                case "SINGLESELECT":
                    let singleSelectCell = self.preferencesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustPrefSingleSelectTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustPrefSingleSelectTableViewCell
                    
                    singleSelectCell.configureCell(of: categoryCode!, with: filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].preferenceValues!, and: filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].code!, withSelectedDefaultValue: filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].value ?? "")
                    
                    singleSelectCell.preferenceTitle.text = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].name
                    
                    
                    if filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].description != nil {
                        singleSelectCell.preferenceDescription.text = filteredPreferenceSet[indexPath.row].description
                    }
                    else {
                        singleSelectCell.preferenceDescription.text = ""
                        singleSelectCell.titleBottomConstraint.constant = 0
                        singleSelectCell.descriptionBottomConstraint.constant = 0
                    }
                    
                    singleSelectCell.radioDelegate = self
                    
                    singleSelectCell.setNeedsLayout()
                    singleSelectCell.layoutIfNeeded()
                    
                    return singleSelectCell
                    
                default:
                    return UITableViewCell()
                    
                }
            }
            else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for each CustomerPreference value? Your problem is that you are using `i` to index into `updatedPrefSet` and `self.preferenceSet`.

Comment: yes, I changed my code to use categoryCode as the unique identifier. Now I have a problem in my cellForRowAt... I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

After spending some good time, I figured out the problem that the logic to update self.preferenceSet with the updatedPrefSet is broken. I removed the if comparison and looped through all elements in the self.preferenceSet. The final working code looks as below -

```
func expandOrCollapseCategory(sender: CategoryGestureRecoginzer, preferenceSet: [CustomerPreference]) {
    let updatedPrefSet = preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode})                      
                
    for i in 0..<self.preferenceSet.filter({$0.categoryCode == sender.categoryCode}).count {
                    
                        self.preferenceSet[i].code = updatedPrefSet[i].code
                        self.preferenceSet[i].dataType = updatedPrefSet[i].dataType
                        self.preferenceSet[i].description = updatedPrefSet[i].description
                        self.preferenceSet[i].name = updatedPrefSet[i].name
                        self.preferenceSet[i].preferenceValues = updatedPrefSet[i].preferenceValues
                        self.preferenceSet[i].value = updatedPrefSet[i].value
                    
                }
                
                let sectionNumber = self.preferenceCategories?.firstIndex(where: {$0.code == sender.categoryCode})
                
                self.preferencesTableView.reloadSections([sectionNumber!], with: .fade)

}
```